# Throwing exceptions without interrupting execution of method

Tags: java, exception

I know and recognize (or I think so) the difference beetwen exception hendling by `try{}catch` block and throwing exceptions by classes or methods, but I wonder, if there is a way, to use `throws` kayword by method, and mentain the execution of this code/method after throwing exception?

I mean, like in example below:

```
public class Main {
    int[] array = {0,1,2};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main object = new Main();
        System.out.println("Dealing inside try{}catch block");
        object.dealInside();
        System.out.println("Dealing by throws keyword");
        try{
            object.throwOutside();
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        }
    }

    public void dealInside(){
         for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
             try{
                 System.out.println(i);
                 int r = array[i];
             }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
             }
         }
    }

    public void throwOutside() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            int r = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

If there is `try{}catch` block inside the loop, method can proceed even if exception occur, and it print int up to 6, even if the length of array is 3. But in case of method which `throws` exception, once interrupted method stops.

1. Is there a way to continue working of method, which `throws`
   exception?
2. Is it possible, to deal at the same time, with multiple methods
   which `throws` similar/same exception, without interruption of
   their execution?

Answer (score 2):

`finally`

This is the exact purpose of the `finally` block. To execute the code inside it no matter if an exception was caught before it or not. It will always execute.
Write some logic to achieve  what you actually want by altering the value of i perhaps inside the finally block.

```
try {
    //risky code
} catch(Exception ex) {
    //handle caught exception
} finally {
    //this part always executes
}
```

Now, the tricky bit. if you really want the for loop to keep going, even if the exception is caught in a subsequent statement, here is what you do.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        void run() {
            try{
                 System.out.println(i);
                 int r = array[i];
             }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
             }
        });
    t.start();
}
```

The `for loop` is running on the main `thread` while the risky code is in a separate thread. So, even if it encounters an exception, the main thread keeps on running as it has no idea about the exception thrown. This is a neat trick. But I don't know if it is a good idea to use it in practice though.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but like in example above, if there is loop in method which throws exception, it will be interrupted and will not proceed, doeasn't it? So there is only finally to finish gracely what method started, but there is no mean to in a fact ignore exeption when it is not in try{}catch block?

Comment: `public void doThis(int i){
 for(; i<6; i++) { try{}catch(Exception e) {} finally { //make changes to i and call doThis(i);} } }`

Comment: And from the main method, call doThis(0); to initiate the process.


 
This is a round about way of acheiving what you want through recursion. To put the for loop inside a method which takes in an integer argument which acts as the initialization argument for the for loop. and then call the same method with the updated value from finally.

Comment: Thank you for this workaround, but it seems that the answer for my questions is: it is not possible to completly ignore exception thrown by methods without interrupting it

Comment: @m.cekiera Hi... i found a solution for your problem. It can be done. All you have to do, is do the check in a new thread. Create a new thread inside the for loop for each block of risky code. So, if the exception occurs, it stops the current thread. yet, the for loop keeps going as the for loop thread never encounters an exception.

Comment: Check out the updated answer. If this is what you were looking for, please do accept the answer.. I really need some reps. :D

Comment: Actually, if `try{}catch` block is inside a loop, you don't really need new thread, just like in example I provide in a question. I asked about case when method use `throws` keyword, is it possible to continue loop anyway? And this is not an answer

Comment: Yes. You are continuing the loop that way. Just try the solution i have given. I have tried and tested it, it does work. You are making a new thread for each iteration. Which handles the tricky bit. And ends after each iteration. If exception occurs. It throws an error. You can catch and handle it in that thread and then let it terminate. But that doesnt affect the for loop. The for loop keeps going with the next iteration.

Comment: Yes, it does, but it will not help me an it is not answer for my question, which was about dealing with exception on other level of application